# Can infrared light rays penetrate through several inches of steel and get a clear image of the heat signature?

Tags: optics

Can infrared cameras detect heat signatures through  thick walls of an average 40 foot steel alloy container used for general cargo in the shipping industry? If so how much power needs to be generated by the infrared camera in order to get a clear image of the heat signature?

Comment: I don't quite understand.  What do you mean by "power generated by the infrared camera"?

Comment: The wall thickness of a typical shipping container is not 'several inches thick', if that were the case, they would be incredibly heavy. The steel sheeting tends to be only a few mm thick, but it is corrugated and has heavier tubular cross-bracing to give structural support.

Comment: Also, how would you classify a 'clear image'? To what level of detail? I think the question is a little unclear, tbh.

Comment: What are your trying to smuggle?

Answer (score 3):

No. IR radiation is easily absorbed by steel and because steel is quite thermally conductive, the incoming heat is quickly shared laterally within the steel sheet. This averages away any spatial information (as in an "image") that the incoming IR may have carried, and an IR imaging sensor on the other side of the sheet would only detect a diffuse glow.

Comment: thanks for the answer , im working on a project and i just needed clarity on that.